# update database table by array in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update database table by array,currently iam using a code which take more time
the code is below

```
  $data = array(
                'name' => $id
                 );

        while($data)
                {
              $pid=$data['name']; 
              mysql_query("UPDATE pm_registration SET status='1' WHERE id='$pid'")or die(mysql_error());
                }
```

is there any other solution ? Any assistance is very much appreciated.

Comment: See IN(). Typically, you would build the query inside the loop and then execute it, once, outside the loop. There is however a caveat to this approach, but maybe someone else can explain what that is

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I see you are using deprecated mysql extension. You are leaving yourself open to lots of security errors and SQL Injection. see [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496) for more detail.

I assume from your question you want to loop through an array and perform the same query you could achieve this by using Prepared statements and passing through the parameters.

e.g.

```
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE pm_registration SET status= :status WHERE id=:name");

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $stmt->execute(["status" => $value['status'], "name" => $value['name']]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me .you are right,using `foreach` instead of `while loop` is better and it take less exicution time.